# Viewing Assets (PDFs) associated with an entry directly from that entry screen

Tags: assets, entry, assets-field

I have a channel with an Assets field, designed to hold PDF files. It works fine to select one or more files, and/or upload files and select them. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to view a PDF once selected, from the add/edit entry screen.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you may have found an answer to this, but have you seen the [download assets](https://plugins.craftcms.com/download-assets) plugin? It puts a download button next to every asset on an edit page that links to the asset's url.

Comment: I had not seen that before, thanks. Another solution I considered was to use one of the UI elements in the field tool, and stick some Twig code in their to loop through all the assets and display links to them. But this plug-in looks to be a better solution.